# Плавная смена картинок с помощью random

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, css

Добрый день!
Нужна помощь в написании скрипта для плавной смены картинок с помощью random, то есть что бы картинки менялись в хаотичном порядке!

Comment: плавная смена картинок != смена картинок в хаотичном порядке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

почему бы не мспользовать прозрачность изображений и определенный шаг в их изменении?
UPD:

```
function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');
    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');
    var $sibs  = $active.siblings();
    var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * $sibs.length );
    var $next  = $( $sibs[ rndNum ] );
    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
       .addClass('active')
       .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
                 $active.removeClass('active last-active');
       });
    }

   $(function() {
       setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
   });
```

и html-пример:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css">

#slideshow {
    position:relative;
    height:350px;
}

#slideshow IMG {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:8;
    opacity:0.0;
}

#slideshow IMG.active {
    z-index:10;
    opacity:1.0;
}

#slideshow IMG.last-active {
    z-index:9;
}

</style>

<body>
<div id="slideshow">
    <img src="image1.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 1" class="active" />
    <img src="image2.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 2" />

    <img src="image3.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 3" />
    <img src="image4.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 4" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: отображается только первое изображение, там где указан  class="active"
и не происходит дальше нечего... в чём может быть загвоздка?

Comment: ну вот зачем так писать?

     setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );

люди, в javascript функция это тип данных, можно писать просто

     setInterval( slideSwitch, 5000 );

Comment: Не серчай - я еще только учусь ;)